cannot import name 'Create_react_agent' from 'langchain.agents'
I am trying to use the langchain agents and unable to load the create_react_agent
using this code
from langchain_google_genai import ChatGoogleGenerativeAI
from langchain import hub
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, Create_react_agent
from langchain_core.tools import Tool

and i am getting this error
from langchain.agents import AgentExecutor, Create_react_agent
ImportError: cannot import name 'Create_react_agent' from 'langchain.agents'

versions:
python 3.11
langchain 0.3.3

Typo: create_react_agent

The error is due to the fact that you are using Captial "c" in Create_react_agent in the langchain.agents module. The correct method is  create_react_agent.

Please do not answer questions that are due to typos; leave a comment and flag the question for closing as such. Plus, in similar cases, a link to the relevant docs is always a good idea.
